# How to serve multiple gcloud service with one domain

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, gcloud, api-gateway, google-cloud-run

I have multiple gcloud services running for different tasks. Some use functions, some app-engine and one is a compute engine machine. 
How can I serve all of theme with one public domain?

I imagine some kind of mapping or routing like :

```
example.de/auth => function A   
example.de/wallet => app-engine default service   
example.de/user => cloud run service   
...
```

I've red that cloud endpoints is the pendant to aws AWS api-gateway. 
But as far as I understand I cannot apply a domain to cloud endpoints in general.

What can I use to build such kind of facade (example.de domain)?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Endpoints are a service that can be run in a docker image, GKE, or Cloud Run.

If you are running Cloud Endpoinsts as a service in Cloudrun then you can configure the custom domain for the the cloud Run service following [This Guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains) which how to add a mapping to a custom domain.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
But the question was more about how to route then from the cloud run service to other services. 
But now I found a example how to do that [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run)